# Sonar-scanner all files

Tags: php, sonarqube, code-analysis, sonarscanner

I am using sonarqube to analyze the code of my project in PHP, everything is set up and partially working, the problem is as follows, I do a check with the Sonar scanner on my pull-requests and merge with the branch master, the analysis it is being carried out, but only in the modified files. I would need to analyze all the code at least on the merge with the master branch. When I go to **Project -> code**, I only have a few files in the master branch.
I would like to know if there is any parameter that can be passed in the scanner so that it always analyzes all files as it is done with the scanner run locally.
Code scanner

```
name: Analyze pull request

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, edited, reopened, synchronize]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  SonarQube-Scanner-pull_request:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Setup sonarqube
        uses: warchant/setup-sonar-scanner@v1

      - name: 'Checkout repository on branch: ${{ github.REF }}'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.HEAD_REF }}

      - name: Retrieve entire repository history
        run: |
          git fetch --prune --unshallow
      - name: Run an analysis of the PR
        env:
          # to get access to secrets.SONAR_TOKEN, provide GITHUB_TOKEN
          GITHUB_TOKEN: 
        run: sonar-scanner
          -Dsonar.host.url=
          -Dsonar.login=
          -Dsonar.projectKey=Project
          -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=${{ github.event.number }}
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=${{ github.HEAD_REF }}
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=${{ github.BASE_REF }}
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.repository=${{ github.repository }}
          -Dsonar.scm.provider=git
          -Dsonar.java.binaries=/tmp
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4nBq.png)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by giving `sonar.projectBaseDir` and `sonar.sources` in sonar analysis properties.
Find more details here [Alternate Analysis Directory](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/)

Comment: sorry for the delay in the response, this configuration is found in sonar-project.properties and even so the whole code is not analyzed.